# Screen Color temperature flickers when watching a video on Safari

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, video, netflix

when I'm watching a video on Safari (i.e. Netflix) every now and then the video momentarily becomes blueish or orange-ish. That would usually happen when the scene is predominantly light colors.

Sometimes the color will persist on regular apps if I stop the video and switch to these apps.

The switching is not consistent. If I rewind the video, the second time I'm watching the scene it usually won't switch colors.

Here is video I just recorded demonstrating the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tc660705c3a8ek5/flicker.mp4?dl=0

This would happen(or sometimes, not happen) any time of the day, regardless if night shift is on or off.

My device is an early 2015 MacBook Air.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it? Looks like this might help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8170327

Comment: @Izap When posting links please make sure to include some content that will answer the users answer in a block quote. Please try to avoid link only answers